# Credentials. rake aborted! ArgumentError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `bin/rails credentials:edit`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, aws-credentials

I try to use capistrano to deploy rails i got this error when i run cap production deploy:initial
I have one branch main in github and one master in the same repo.
I use branch master but when i run say that
ake aborted!
01
01 ArgumentError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `bin/rails credentials:edit`
01

I run rails credentials:edit -e production and put the secret key base in there
i run bin/rails secret to get a credentials and put that in credentials -e production.
When i rung again cap production deploy:initial i got  the same error.
How i can fix that?
I use rails 7.0.8 and ruby 3.2.2

How i can fix that?
I already have the credentials in env production.yml file